# Regex for non-alphabets, non-numerals and non-DOT

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Please provide a solution to write a regular expression as following in C#.NET: I would require a RegEx as below:

Non-Alphabets(a to z;A to Z) and Non-Numerals(0 to 9) and also non-DOT (.). Mean to say as otherthan the mentioned above i want to handle reverse way for getting regular expression as other than alphabets, otherthan numerals(0 to 9) otherthan DOT(.).

Kindly suggest the solution for the same.

The Regex:  [^a-zA-Z0-9] fails when i use DOT(.) in a string such as 'Test.01'

Answer (score 5):

`[^a-zA-Z0-9.]`

Comment: period is not a special character inside a character class - `[^a-zA-Z0-9.]` would suffice

Comment: I got a compiler error for \. too - unrecognised escape sequence

Comment: @Jon: That's probably because you forgot to prefix your regex string with `@` to make it a verbatim literal.

Answer (score 2):

See related (almost dup) [regex for non alphabets and non numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754758/regex-for-non-alphabets-and-non-numerals)

Answer (score 0):

You could write C# code like so:

```
string pattern = "^[a-z0-9.]$";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (!reg.IsMatch(yourStringInput))
{
      // throw error or w/e
}
```