# Java regex to validate the beginning of a list of strings

Tags: java, regex, validation

If I have a list of strings say:

```
private List<String> domains;
```

How do I validate the strings and create a boolean to confirm they all start with a symbol that is not a word or number?

Result of string should be something like:

```
@yahoo.com
)cloud.com
```

and not:

```
yahoo.com
cloud.com
```

I have

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/[^\\w._\\s]/g");
Matcher m = p.matcher(values.getList().get(0)); //right now it's only checking first element I'm not sure how to check them all
boolean b = m.matches();
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for non-alphabets and non-numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754758/regex-for-non-alphabets-and-non-numerals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using Java 8 (or higher), you can make use of the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^a-zA-Z0-9].*");
boolean all = domains.stream().allMatch(st -> p.matcher(st).matches());
```

`all` then contains a boolean that checks if all the domains match the regex.

The regex matches everything that doesn't start with a lowercase, uppercase character or a numeric character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`matcher.lookingAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--) with a simple regex `\\W` that means a non-word character (that includes non letters and non digits) like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W");
boolean status = true;

for (String str : domains) {
   Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
   if ((status = m.lookingAt()) == false) {
      break;
   }
}

System.out.println( status );
```

`lookingAt` attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning of the region, against the pattern.

btw you are mixing Javascript regex syntax in Java. There is no `/..../g` in Java.

Comment: I want the bool to be true/false only once, and that's if all of the strings in the list meet the pattern requirement