# How to check whether the string contains special characters or not in vb.net?

Tags: string, vb.net, special-characters

I want to check whether the input contains special characters(@"[~`!@#$%^&*()-+=|{}':;.,<>/?]") or not in vb.net?

How can I check that in vb.net code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for non-alphabets and non-numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754758/regex-for-non-alphabets-and-non-numerals)

Comment: so you just want to know if the input have something else then numbers and letters. correct?

Comment: Yes.how to find that in vb.net code?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check if any of the mentioned characters are contained in the string you can use the following function:

```
Function ContainsSpecialChars(s As String) As Boolean
    Return s.IndexOfAny("[~`!@#$%^&*()-+=|{}':;.,<>/?]".ToCharArray) <> -1
End Function
```

Or if you want to check if the string just contains letters, digits or whitespace, you can use the following function:

```
Function ContainsSpecialChars(s As String) As Boolean
    Return s.Any(Function(c) Not (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) OrElse Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
End Function
```

Comment: you forgot to filter for white space

Answer (score 2):

If the string can only contain letters or digits(0-9) or white-spaces:

```
Dim noSpecialCharacters = text.
    All(Function(c) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) OrElse Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))

Dim containsSpecialCharacters = Not noSpecialCharacters
```

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
            Handles Button1.Click
            Dim noSpecialCharacters = text.
             All(Function(c) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) OrElse 
             Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))

              Dim containsSpecialCharacters = Not noSpecialCharacters 
              End Sub                                                                                     Can I paste this code inside the button or  anything else I want to add?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import this namespace : Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
2. Create a public function which checks all inputs Excepts : 0-9,a-z,A-Z

   `Public Function ContainsSpecialCharacters(Input As String) As Boolean

   ```
    Dim pattern As String = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]"
    Dim regex As New Regex(pattern)

    Return regex.IsMatch(input)
   ```

   End Function`
3. Use it in your Code :

   If ContainsSpecialCharacters("yourtext") Then
   str = ("Special character is not allowed in text.")
   return Str

Note : number 3 is the code used in my logic ,you have to edit it for your case.